# How do I layer video clips of different resolutions within a Scene that has a single, consistent Render resolution?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have video clips of different resolutions I want to layer within the same Scene / Render Size. What are preferred methods to accomplish this?

I've been able to scale individual Movie strips by adding and adjusting a `Transform Effect` strip to each. For each source clip, this involved manually getting resolution info, calculating the scale relative to the Scene dimensions, and adding these pixel dimensions to each clips' Transform Effect.

If this is the preferred method to accomplish this, 1) can I access source Movie strip resolution outside of `Sequencer Context Menu ... Movie Strip ... Set Render Size`?

UPDATE: The [Media Info Extractor add-on](https://github.com/tin2tin/MediaInfoExtractor) addresses my strip resolution question with **Source** info added to the Strip panel.

[image]

2) When I create a `Meta Strip` from the source video and Transform strip, is there a way to access the Transform strips' scale values without UnMeta-ing?

Accessing the scale value of the Transform strip within the Meta Strip allows me to adjust the proportions of each Movie strip within the Scene dimensions. UnMeta-ing strips causes loss of adjustments made to the Meta Strip -- e.g. Compositing, Offset, and Crop values. UnMeta-ing strips can also throw off Sequencer Track order which throws off layer hierarchies.

[This q re mixing framerates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96500/problem-mixing-a-scene-with-video-clips-in-the-vse) didn't address my use case. I'm delving into [the Compositor and Crop nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57766/can-i-put-a-small-resolution-scene-on-top-of-a-large-scene-in-one-go) while hoping I can remain in the VSE

Comment: Suggestion. State your goal clearly.  What was successful and what was not successful ... spelled out. A specific question with a question mark would help.  I do see one question there .. but there seems to be a lot of room for interpretation.  Why do you want to  access to the scale value? if you care to explain.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and feedback. I will update my title as an explicit question and spell more out in the post.